# OpenCv merge. Uninitialized _dims member when using cv::merge

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a problem with using `cv::merge()` function. Calling it causes assertion error: `CV_Assert( 0 <= _dims && _dims <= CV_MAX_DIM )`. I have run program in debugger and I have noticed that `_dims` is uninitialized (each run different random value). Sometimes program execution passes assert and the memory access error occurs( in `void Mat::copySize(const Mat& m)`). Below are 2 member function that are involved in process of calling `cv::merge` (mImages member contains valid data, when I am displaying single channel image [in gray scale] program executes properly. If you have questions how data is contained please refer to cifar10 data description on http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html, but as I said all input data during program execution is valid):

```
cv::Mat DataPackage::formatSingleChannelImage(std::vector<unsigned const char> const &channelData, DataPackage::RGB channel)
{
    unsigned channelBeg = 0;
    switch (channel)
    {
    case DataPackage::RGB::RED:
        channelBeg = 0;
        break;
    case DataPackage::RGB::GREEN:
        channelBeg = 1024;
        break;
    case DataPackage::RGB::BLUE:
        channelBeg = 2 * 1024;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cv::Mat singleChannelImg = cv::Mat::zeros(colsN, rowsN, CV_8UC1);
    std::vector<unsigned char> tmp;

    for (unsigned col = 0; col < colsN; ++col)
    {
        for (unsigned row = 0; row < rowsN; ++row)
        {
            singleChannelImg.at<unsigned char>(row, col) = (unsigned const char)channelData[channelBeg+(col*rowsN + row)];  
        }
    }

    return singleChannelImg;
}

cv::Mat DataPackage:: makeImage(unsigned id)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(colsN, rowsN, CV_8UC3);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;

    channels.push_back(formatSingleChannelImage(mImages[id], DataPackage::RGB::RED));
    channels.push_back(formatSingleChannelImage(mImages[id], DataPackage::RGB::GREEN));
    channels.push_back(formatSingleChannelImage(mImages[id], DataPackage::RGB::BLUE));

    cv::merge(channels, image);

    return image;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's `channelBeg`? What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just using `split`? This snippet doesn't seem sufficient to understand the crash

Comment: @Miki `mImages` is not container with actual images. It contains values of  pixels. Values are stored as follows: 3072 bytes are the values of the pixels of the image. The first 1024 bytes are the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The values are stored in row-major order, so the first 32 bytes are the red channel values of the first row of the image. So `channelBeg` is first index where given channel starts. I dont know why are you asking about `split`, I need to merge channels.

Comment: Because of the way you compute `singleChannelImg`. Ok now I got it (split is not useful, but you can improve a lot :D). The rest of the code seems ok (aside from `cv::Mat::zeros(colsN, rowsN, CV_8UC3);`. You should invert rowsN and colsN, but you can as well leave `Mat image;` without initialization.) So, without further info, it's hard to understand where the error could be, because (at least to me), it's not in the code you showed

Comment: BTW, you can replace the creation of `singleChannelImg` with: `Mat1b singleChannelImg = Mat1b(rowsN, colsN, channelData.data() + channelBeg).clone();`

Comment: And also in your code should probably be `row*rowsN + col`, you got lucky because the images are squared

Comment: @Miki Sorry for delay. I've checked if it is problem with `singleChannelImg` computing. I've pushed to `channels` vector `cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(colsN, rowsN, CV_8UC3)`  3 times (so now all channels are 0) and same error occurred.